# Basic Hashing Concepts

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I have a very basic question. believe me I have read many books, saw videos but not able to get my answer.
Suppose we have HashMap.
I have 3(a,b,c) vales that maps to same hash, a and b are same but c is different.
If I add only a and b to hastable, how does hashMap knows it is NOT a collision.

Suppose we have Hashmap.... Now I call put(obj1,"Test") and then put(obj2,"Test") obj1 and obj2 map to same key.... Can you tell me what hash map is going to store for these two calls

Will it store the actual objects? 
If no how will it decide on the second call that it is not collision if obj1 and obj2 are same.

Thanks

Comment: Because a and b are the same?

Comment: But as far as I know HashTable only knows about keys not actual key values i.e. say a and b map to key k, I think hashtable only knows about k not a and b. Am I wrong?

Comment: If a and b are identical, then it **is** a collision. Did you meant to ask how it distinguishes a/b and *c*? In any case, your question is **very** basic and has been answer before.

Comment: @delnan are you saying if a and b are identical, it is a collison? and yes I want to know how to distinguish b/w a/b and c

Answer (score 1):

Most hashtables require two bits of support from your storage objects - GetHashCode() and Equals().

If two objects return the same GetHashCode() but their comparison with Equals() returns true, they represent the same data, and thus is not a collision, just duplicate entries.

If two objects return the same GetHashCode(), and their comparison returns false, then the Hashtable knows that the objects represent different things, and thus treats it as a collision.

This is why in many oop languages, like C#, you have to overrride/implement GetHashCode() and Equals() in your storage objects. If you ever implement those methods such that two objects, when compared with Equals() returns true, but return different values from GetHashCode(), then you have a bug.

Comment: So do you say that HashTable stores the actual key objects..... I thought it stores only the value..

Comment: @user973931 If it stored only the key, how would it return the value given the key? Of course, it couldn't.

Comment: @delnan it would calculate the hash and return the value at index

Comment: @user973931 So it *would* store the value ;)

Comment: @user973931, that wouldn't work because then it couldn't handle collisions. A simple hashtable implementation would have one array for the buckets that would be indexed into using the hashcode, and then each index stores another array. Lookups work by going to the bucket for the given hashcode and then walking down the array until you find the key where Equals returns true with the passed in key.

Comment: Suppose we have Hashmap<MyClass, String>.... Now I call put(obj1,"Test") and then put(obj2,"Test") obj1 and obj2 map to same key.... Can you tell me what hash map is going to store for these two calls

Comment: Depends on the semantics of the hashmap. If obj1 and obj2 have the same hashcode and are Equal to each other, the hashmap is going to treat that as a duplicate key and overwrite the value. The hashmap would do the same thing it would do if you had done put(obj1, "A"), put(obj1, "B")

Comment: Furthermore, if you did:  put(obj1, "Test");  val = get(obj2); then val would be "Test".

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia:

> In computer science, a hash table or hash map is a data structure that
>   uses a hash function to map identifying values, known as keys (e.g., a
>   person's name), to their associated values (e.g., their telephone
>   number). Thus, a hash table implements an associative array.

Also Wiki said associative array as "abstract data type composed of a collection of (key,value) pairs".

So yes, the hash table do know their "tenants".

Comment: So If I use HashTable<MyClass,Integer>.. How much memory does it need.. I think memory needed would be HashTable Size() * Integer Size... If this is correct where does it store tenants